# List the modified files using an IntelliJ plugin

Tags: plugins, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin

How can I retrieve the list of locally modified classes within an IntelliJ plugin?

Is there any IntelliJ plugin tutorial / opensource project that is relevant to the case above?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your luck (I'm serious).

First, open `View | Recent Changes` (You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Windows/Linux), and there's a list of your changes.

If you're lucky enough, you'll find the version you want. And you can revert to that version by clicking `revert` at bottom-right.

If you're using Git, use this tool window.
[image]